# Make WebSphere listen on IPv4

Tags: websphere, websphere-8, ipv4

I have a WebSphere application server 8, where I have deployed an enterprise application. Now I want to make that web GUI of that application reachable. So I set up a port (9080), added a web container transport chain, added a virtual host for port 9080, and added that virtual host to my deployed application. However, it is not reachable.

Digging through WebSphere's log, I found this message:

```
TCPC0001I: TCP Channel TCP_6 is listening on host *  (IPv6) port 9080.
```

So apparently, the channel listens on IPv6, not on IPv4. I verified this with netstat, which indeed shows that the server's process only listens on IPv6. How do I make the channel listen on IPv4 instead? I already tried setting `java.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` in the server's JVM, but that didn't change anything.

Interestingly, Websphere's console is available via IPv4, but I cannot figure out what part of it is configured differently so that it works, while my setup does not.

Comment: Not reachable by TCP (connection refused?) Or something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On many operating systems IPv6 sockets on the wildcard address (`*` or `::/0`) can accept both IPv4 and IPv6 connections. On for example Mac OS netstat would show such sockets as i.e. `tcp46` to show they are dual-stack. Other operating systems, including Linux, just show them as `tcp6` even if they also accept IPv4 connections.

So it is probably listening on IPv4 just fine, it's just a confusing way of showing it to the sysadmin.

Comment: That was actually the problem. Not sure if I should feel stupid now or rant at netstat.